# Eclipse always exit when used in a virtual machine

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, virtual-machine

I use ubuntu16.04 in VMware for learning Hadoop. The eclipse is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers at 2020.03 for linux_64.

And when use eclipse to write some java code, the IDE usually exits by itself without any error. And the eclipse is too slow when I use it. I guess that whether the memory is not enough for using IDE. But I found the memory is free when I check it. I allocated 2G of memory for ubuntu16.04.

And I search for this problem on web. I found many people believe the problem is eclipse caused. So they come up with a way to edit eclipse.ini.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Add this command to the last line of eclipse.ini.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. So Do u know why? Should I allocate more memory for VMware?

Comment: It's good to include the Ubuntu version. What is the Eclipse version?

Comment: Thanks for your remind. My eclipse version is "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020.03" for linux_64.